# Deploy custom Maven archetype to Artifactory

Tags: maven, artifactory, archetypes

I try hardly to deploy my own archetype to the Artifactory.
http://www.java-redefined.com/2013/10/create-custom-archetype-and-deploy-on.html

I followed this tutorial but after trying to do:
`mvn archetype:generate` in a folder the archetype can not be found.

Maven as Mirror works.

The archetype-catalog.xml contains:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><archetype-catalog>
<archetypes>   
     <archetype>      
         <groupId>de.custom.transformation</groupId>      
         <artifactId>camel-route-template</artifactId>      
         <version>0.0.1</version>       
         <repository>https://artifactory.custom.de/artifactory/mbts-release-local<repository>      
         <description>camel-route-template</description>    
     </archetype>  
 </archetypes>
 </archetype-catalog>
```

Can anyone help me and give some hints?

Comment: can you find the artifact in the repository with its artifactId? The archetype catalog maybe needs to be regenerated after uploading (deployment) of the archetype into your artifactory repository.

Comment: Okay now it works. The catalog should not deployed as artifact, just as xml file.